# While extracting tags from website list is extracted as series of list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract forum names from the website, when I am trying to extract names each item in the list is getting added up to subsequent item in the list.

```
url = "https://www.f150forum.com/f118"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
domains = soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class":"trow text-center"})
htags = [i.find_all('h4') for i in domains]
forum = []
for x in htags:
    for i in x :
        results = [i.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
        forum.append(results)
        print(len(forum))
```

Len(forum) should be 59 where as it is showing as 1,2,3...59. What should I do to extract each h4 as an item in list?

Comment: it's showing that because you are printing the length in the loop. Unindent the last print statement and you should just see `59`

Comment: You are seeing 1, 2, 3... because you have the `print()` inside the loop. Do you want that the list `forum` contains only 59 strings from `<h4>`? Or 59 lists, each containing one string from `<h4>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `print(len(forum))` inside `for i in x` where `len(x)=59` and inside one more exactly same loop `for x in htags:`. This is the reason you see 59 times 1,2,...59.

Here how it should be:

```
url = "https://www.f150forum.com/f118"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
htags = soup.select(".trow h4")
forum = []
for h in htags:
    print(h.text)
    forum.append(h.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
```